# PivotItemHeader in two rows?

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm currently building an app where I use a `PivotControl` as the standard navigation. I managed to style the headers now but after some thought I realised that I should probably make the whole app sizeable for different screens. Not every screen (especially in IoT scenarios) will be a full HD screen :D

Thats the current control:
[image]

My problem now is that when I make the screen and the `PivotItem` smaller it just cuts off the end of the pivots like you can see at the right of the picture. 
What I would rather have is that when the `PivotItem` gets smaller I want the `Headers` to stack.

Like in this quickly googled example:

[image]

But I don't know how I should make that possible...
Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to build?
Could the content be organized in other way?

Pivots or similar controls (tabs, segmented controls etc) work best with few items that are important to the user and deserve the central stage. 
The screenshot you added violates several UI best practices and I suggest you find an alternative to structure your UI that is user friendly.

Comment: I don't have that many items. I have just 6 items. Currently I try to make the app resizable because I totally forgot about that in the beginning because I'm new to this... So I just want to stack 2 rows of 3 when the screen gets smaller ...  what user friendly approach would you suggest?

Comment: Oh, 6 is not as many as you showed in the example so it should be possible to make it work.

Can you share some screenshots of your app?
Ideally it would be great to stop at 4 maybe 5 items, the common candidates for removing are items that don't belong on the same group as the rest (e.g. settings, profile etc).
You can also use other strategies for adaptive layout, like hiding components or changing the layout for certain resolutions.
Another option would be HamburgerMenu. While not to most intuitive, it does adapt to lower resolutions well and can accomodate more items than the pivot.

Comment: It was just a really quickly googled example to show what I wanted to do. I know it's a bit overkill but thats the first one I found :D I will make a screen of my app when I'm back at work. Maybe I will really change it to a HamburgerMenu since I just saw that it's implemented into UWP with a NavigationView now...